# Why can we use this density for random variables with normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, density-function

We have given $N\sim \mathfrak{N}(0;1)$, $x\in \Bbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$. Furthermore $f$ is continuous and bounded. Then we want to compute $E(f(x+\epsilon N))$

We have just proven that for a random variable $X=x+\epsilon N$ the density is $$f_x(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y-x}{\epsilon}\right)^2\right)$$

Thus I thought that $$E(f(x+\epsilon N))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+\epsilon y) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y-x}{\epsilon}\right)^2\right) dy$$
But our prof instead wrote $$E(f(x+\epsilon N))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+\epsilon y) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)dy$$

He said something like both works but is this true? And if yes why does the second one works I don’t see this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The correct formula is $$E(f(x+\epsilon N))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+\epsilon y) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)dy$$ (no $\epsilon$ in the square root). You want to express that $N$ has mean zero and variance one and its integration variable is $y$.

Comment: @KurtG. But why I mean isn’t it $E(f(X))=\int f(x)f_X(x) dx$ where $f_X$ is the first density I gave above

Comment: Dominik Kutek has just answered also that question in a marvelous way. Please accept it if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a random variable with distribution $\mu_X$ and $h$ is any measurable function, then $$ \mathbb E[h(X)] = \int_{\mathbb R} h(x)d\mu_X(x).$$ If $\mu_X$ has density $g$ with respect to Lebesgue Measure, it is the same as $$ \mathbb E[h(X)] = \int_{\mathbb R}h(x)g(x)dx.$$

In your case, you have $f(x+\varepsilon N)$ which can be viewed in different ways. Either as $f(X)$ where $X \sim x + \varepsilon N \sim \mathcal N(x,\varepsilon^2)$, which would give you $$ \mathbb E[f(x+\varepsilon N)] = \mathbb E[f(X)] = \int_{\mathbb R} f(y)d\mu_{\mathcal N(x,\varepsilon^2)}(y) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(y) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\varepsilon}\exp\left(- \frac{(x-y)^2}{2\varepsilon^2}\right)dy$$ (note that under $f$ there is only $y$, and $\varepsilon$ is not under $\sqrt{.}$ sign in the denominator) or $f(x+\varepsilon N)$ can be viewed as $h(N)$, where $h(y) = f(x+\varepsilon y)$, which would give you $$ \mathbb E[f(x+\varepsilon N)] = \mathbb E[h(N)] = \int_{\mathbb R}h(y) d\mu_N(y) = \int_{\mathbb R}f(x+\varepsilon y)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)dy $$ (note that $\varepsilon$ is not in the denominator).